# Can i set different color for different category

Tags: php, css, magento, magento-1.9

Can i set color for button header and other element form page to another color with different  category?

exam.

in my homepage my page color is red ,
when i change category to shirt color is change to blue, 
and change to shoe color is change to pink.

how can i do for set this in admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage color of category from Admin > Manage categories -> Custom Layout -> Custom Layout Update and paste below given code:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/custom_category_1.css</stylesheet>
        <params>media="all"</params>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Define the custom background in the css. Override the default styling by adding !important